# C# Winforms event for both scrollbar buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, widget, scrollbar

Is there an event for each of the two buttons in the vertical scrollbar widget?

I'm using Winforms in C#.

Comment: Did you read about all the details in the eventargs passed to your event handler?

Comment: No. But now I have, and the answer has become immediately obvious. Shall I paste the answer myself and tick it, or would you like to, and I'll tick yours?

Comment: cool cooperation, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handler gets passed some eventargs (including `ScrollEventArgs e`). Look out for `SmallDecrement` and `SmallIncrement` in the ScrollEventArgs's `Type` property.